# Who does decoding for URLencoding?

Tags: java, decoding, url-encoding

I have encoded my string(Say String a="123+gtyt") using **URLEncoder** class.The encoded string is **String b**. Then I am sending "String b" as a parameter appended to a URL. Lets say to **http://example.com?request=b**.

When I Decode the String at example.com using URLDecoder,**The symbol + in my String is missing and I am not getting "String a" after decoding**

Now When I print without decoding the "String b" at example.com.**I get String a exactly**.

**So my doubt is whether the decoding is done by browser itself while redirecting?**

Comment: Could you show the exact code you're using?

Comment: For encoding<br> String xmlString1=URLEncoder.encode(xmlString,"utf-8");
        String reqString = "http://example.com/saml/IDProvider"+"?SAMLRequest=" + xmlString1;

Comment: @Torious For decoing at example.com, String response=request.getParameter("response");<br>String xmlString2=URLDecoder.decode(response,"utf-8")

Comment: You don't have to decode "response", it's already been decoded automatically.

Comment: Not by the browser, but server-side. Probably by HttpServletRequest itself (since it also depends on the set encoding), but not sure where the decoding is actually typically done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you encode "123+gtyt" - it encodes the plus sign.

When you handle an HTTP request, servlet API automaticaly decodes it to "123+gtyt". If you decode it once again - it changes the "+" to a space.

So the key is - do not decode parameters explicitly.

For example:

```
    final String encoded = URLEncoder.encode("123+gtyt");
    final String decoded = URLDecoder.decode(encoded);
    System.out.println("decoded = " + decoded); // 123+gtyt
    System.out.println("URLDecoder.decode(decoded) = " 
              + URLDecoder.decode(decoded)); // prints 123 gtyt
```

Comment: Is there any way to stop servlet API automaticaly decoding the encoded string

Comment: The short answer is no. Just do not decode what comes from the API.

Comment: You can up my question if u wish to :P